# JSF Inplace - Save Value in focusOut

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to save values on ***Focus out*** in **Inplace** JSF. Currently the editor tag can be used but it will display a save/cancel button.
My requirement is to save the data on focus out.

This is the Inplace tag that i am using.

```
 <p:inplace id="basic">  
         <p:inputText value="Edit Me" />  
 </p:inplace>
```

Is there any ajax event like.

```
<p:ajax event="Something like focusOut" listener="#{bean.myFunction()}"/>
```

My Code sample when i use Blur as ajax event

```
<p:inplace label="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.selectedService.statusStr}"  id="ajaxInplaceStatusEdit" >
<p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.inplaceEdit('StatusEdit')}" update="view" oncomplete="scheduleWidget.update();"/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="statusEditImplace" required="true"
 value="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.selectedService.status}"
 label="text">
<f:selectItems value="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.serviceStatusList}"
 var="status" itemLabel="#{status.title}" itemValue="#{status.id}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</p:inplace>
```

The error message That i get when using this event

```
    /WEB-INF/views/service/servicecalendarview.xhtml @886,153 <p:ajax>
 Event:blur is not supported.
```

Comment: This question is obviously JSF 2, not JSF 1.2. Please use the right tags.

Comment: sorry beginner, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`onblur`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) event:

> Execute a JavaScript when a user leaves an input field:

JSF code:

```
<p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{bean.myFunction()}"/>
```

EDIT: from your posted code, the `<p:ajax>` affects the `<p:inplace>` where it should affect the `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Move the `<p:ajax>` inside the `<p:selectOneMenu>`:

```
<p:inplace label="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.selectedService.statusStr}"
    id="ajaxInplaceStatusEdit" >
    <p:selectOneMenu id="statusEditImplace" required="true"
        value="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.selectedService.status}"
        label="text">
        <f:selectItems value="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.serviceStatusList}"
            var="status" itemLabel="#{status.title}" itemValue="#{status.id}" />
        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{serviceCalendarViewManagedBean.inplaceEdit('StatusEdit')}"
            update="view" oncomplete="scheduleWidget.update();"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:inplace>
```

Comment: I am getting an error message 
<p:ajax> Event:blur is not supported.

Comment: @user2731899 edit your question and show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to reproduce your problem.